# Where can I find statistics on good/evil wins for the Resistance:Avalon for different role setups?

Tags: statistics, the-resistance-avalon

I'm trying to nail down exactly which roles work best for different numbers of players.  While I have much anecdotal evidence from many game plays, I was wondering if anyone is actually keeping track and has hard numbers?

For example, I'd like to be able to answer if, for a 9 player games, Merlin+Percy+Morgana+Mordred is more or less close to an even win percentage than the same game without Morgana

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out the [Board Game Geek Avalon community](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/128882/resistance-avalon). People regularly record their play sessions and the users on the forums are usually willing to go into in-depth analysis and discussion on game setup and configuration. For instance, even one of the most recent forum discussions is about [statistical anomalies in Avalon games](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1182429/weirdfun-statistical-anomalies-your-games).

Comment: I've looked there and didn't find what I was looking for.  Any more specific links to this specific question?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience to much revolves around the players skill and play style to track from group to group. What may be a balanced combination for some groups will be unbalanced for others. What you need to look at instead is what does the roles you are adding in do to the game balance (according to the rule book) and start making changes from there. From what I have seen when I have played in different groups the win/loss for good/evil will vary from group to group even for a basic setup.

Percival and Oberon will make the good side more powerful

Morderd and Morgana will make the evil side more powerful

It is just a matter of tweaking the balance based on your groups play style and skill and you will probably find that the balance will change as you play it more often.